# Django - csv.reader and save()/update

Tags: python, django, csv, file-upload

I am trying to update a field or multiple fields from my DB by reuploading a CSV-File with a changed value.

I tried this:

views.py

```
def file_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            id = 0
            das2 = CSV3.objects.all().values_list()
            csv_file = request.FILES['file']
            with open(str(csv_file)) as file:       
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                for row in reader:
                    id += 1
                    try:
                        _, p = CSV3.objects.get_or_create(id = id, defaults = {'gebaeudebereich' : row[0],
                                                                'gebaeudenummer' : row[1], 'ebene' : row[2],
                                                                'raum' : row[3], 'dose' : row[4], 'switch_ip' : row[5],
                                                                'switch_port' : row[6], 'datum' : row[7], 'akteur' : row[8]})

                    except IntegrityError:
                        for i in das2:
                            i[1] = row[0]
                            i.save()


                    return redirect('appp:index')
    form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(
    request, "appp/file_upload.html", {"form": form}
    )
```

I looped through the values and set value 'gebaeudebereich' to the gebaeudebereich value in the CSV-File (I would do this with the other fields too but this is the idea I tried). It is not saving anything and it does not give me an error, just doesn't do anything.
The try clause works just fine.

my models.py

```
class CSV3(models.Model):
    gebaeudebereich = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gebaeudenummer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ebene = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    raum = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dose = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    switch_ip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    switch_port = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datum = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    akteur = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("gebaeudebereich", "gebaeudenummer", "ebene", "raum", "dose"), ("switch_ip", "switch_port"))
```

It cannot be that difficult to update the database with a file upload. I hope you will help me, because I am trying to figure this out for way too long.

Comment: You need to help yourself with a bit of debugging. Where is it failing? When it gets to the get_or_create, does it get or create? You catch IntegrityErrors; what makes you think that code raises those errors? If the result of the get_or_create is a get, where are you updating the object you received?

Comment: Hint: you almost certainly want to use [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) rather than get_or_create.

Comment: You'll never have an `IntegrityError` because `get_or_create` is always going to succeed. Look at your code.

Comment: The exception is because of my unique_together constraint, otherwise it gives me an IntegrityError (of course), so I wanted to handle it by updating the fields. When I add an entry to my file it creates a new row, so that works fine. update_or_create and update() are not helpful in this situation because I learned here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915123/model-save-not-called-on-update) that update does not call save() and that is what I need.

Comment: So I tried iterating over the current values and then override them with the new ones and then save them

Comment: But you're getting on `id` only. So if the `id` already exists in the table, it just fetches the row (and does further nothing with it). If the `id` doesn't exist, it'll create a new row with that id. It'll never raise an IntegrityError because you know for sure the `id` doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Are you really trying to override the entire table with the contents of the CSV file? Why not just first delete the entire table and then write all entries from the CSV file? That would be more efficient: `CSV3.objects.all().delete()` and then loop through your rows to create new entries.

Comment: Okey thank you. I'll try it out. I have another quick question (it would be a waste to open up a new question for that). When I do `v = CSV3.objects.all().update()` or something similar how do I save the changes to the DB, because everytime I tried  `v.save()` it doesn't work.

Comment: Well actually I need to keep the `id` so I cannot delete and upload everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this solution.

```
def file_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
         count = 0
        if form.is_valid():
             csv_file = request.FILES['file']
            with open(str(csv_file)) as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                for row in reader:
                    count += 1

                    try:

                        _, p = Excel1.objects.update_or_create(id = count, defaults = 
                              {'gebaeudebereich' : row[0], 'gebaeudenummer' : row[1],
                              'ebene' : row[2], 'raum' : row[3], 'dose' : row[4],
                              'switch_ip' : row[5], 'switch_port' : row[6], 'datum' : row[7], 'akteur' : row[8]})


                    except IntegrityError:
                        return render(request, 'testapp/duplicate_error.html', {'row' 
: row})

                return redirect('testapp:index')
    form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(
    request, "testapp/file_upload.html", {"form": form}
    )
```